# Whatsapp Chat History TXT File very long, display name of group participants spelled different in some parts of the chat

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

This is very strange. I downloaded a 400 page Whatsapp chat history from a group chat. I noticed that one of the group participants their name is spelled different in parts of the chat. The time stamp in certain areas of the chat are out of order as well. I deleted the group chat on my phone and only have this file. What went wrong?